# angularjs, need help understanding $compile function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found a great working example to display a filetree with AngularJS:
http://jsfiddle.net/n8dPm/

I'm trying to understand the code. What's not clear to me is what happens here:

```
var compiledContents;
return function(scope, iElement, iAttr) {
    if(!compiledContents) {
        compiledContents = $compile(contents);
    }

compiledContents(scope, function(clone, scope) {
    iElement.append(clone); 
});
```

To me it looks like first compiledContents is used to compile contents, next compiledContents is called as a function?

Could someone explain this?

Comment: `$compile` return link function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions can return functions in Javascript.

Note the [documentation for $compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile), which says:

> Compiles an HTML string or DOM into a template and produces a template function, which can then be used to link scope and the template together.

Comment: So first "compiledContents = $compile(contents)" is fired, this produces a template function. Then "compiledContents(scope, function(clone, scope)" and it runs the template function?